# Determine if grid in floatable panel is visible

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a grid inside a collapsed panel that is `floatable` in Ext JS 5.1.1.451.

I cannot find a reliable to way to know if that grid is visible to a user before and after its container panel is floated.

Please see a demo at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vba and look at the console log when the app runs.

After the parent container is rendered, it is collapsed (the grid I care about is hidden), I get conflicting reports about its visiblity depending on what method I use.

***Please note, these results only occur when the user floats the panel before expanding the panel.***

`grid.isVisible()` returns `true`

`grid.isVisible(true)` returns `false` ==> **CORRECT RESULT**

`grid.el.isVisible()` returns `true`

`grid.el.isVisible(true)` returns `true`

When I test the grid's visiblity after I click on the parent container's header to make the panel float (I do not click the `expand` button), I get the following results:

`grid.isVisible()` returns `true` ==> **CORRECT RESULT**

`grid.isVisible(true)` returns `false`

`grid.el.isVisible()` returns `true` ==> **CORRECT RESULT**

`grid.el.isVisible(true)` returns `true` ==> **CORRECT RESULT**

What is the proper way to reliably test a grid's visibility when I do not know its parent's status of being collapsed/expanded/floated?

Comment: Why don't you check for `!!grid.ownerCt.getCollapsed()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think using `!floatingPanel.getCollapsed()` will get you your expected result.

Have a look: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vbv